# SQL Server 2005 Analysis Service (SSAS) Partial Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, ssas, olap, data-synchronization

I'm new to SSAS (this is my first project that involves ssas).

I have a regular a SQL Server 2005 server (say Blah) that run database instance and sql server analysis service. I want to synchronize some of the data in Blah (based on some condition) to another server, Blah2. Partial data sync is quite straightforward with the help of replication server. However, I'm not sure how to do a partial data synchronization for the analysis service.

I have a table in Blah database that list all of the cubes in its analysis service. I then need to filter this table to list all the necessary cube and this is ok. But I'm sure how to continue from there.

I've looked into the SSAS Database Sync Wizard but I couldnt find any command line tools for this or a way to run this as procedure in SQL Script (I will need to do this as a regular sql server job, so it's necessary not to rely on gui). Even if I want to use the gui, there doesnt seems to be a way to filter the cube/measurement from the gui.

I'm thinking of getting the cube, measurement, data source view, etc dynamically but I cant find a way to get these definitions dynamically from sql script. I'm trying to do simple openquery to get list of cube in sql server screen with this (olap_server is a linked server to the ssas):

```
select *
from openquery(olap_server, 'select [CATALOG_NAME]
from $system.dbschema_catalogs')
```

with no luck. I got the "An error occurred while preparing the query "select [CATALOG_NAME]
from $system.dbschema_catalogs" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "olap_server"." error instead.

Is there any straightforward way to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at doing something similar...

You can synchronize without using the Database Sync Wizard gui by issuing an XMLA Synchronize command against the Target database as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187156.aspx
or for 2005 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187156(SQL.90).aspx

Your SQL Server job will need to have a step of type "SQL Server Analyis Services Command"

An example and some more background info is here: http://dwbijourney.blogspot.com/2008/01/ssas-database-synchronization-for.html

Comment: hanks for the answer.

That does solve the gui problem but it still doesnt provide me a way to filter the cube.

Have you tried the RoboCopy solution? I've tried this yesterday and the file were copied but the database structure wasnt refreshed in SMSS.

Comment: I haven't tried the RoboCopy solution so can't really add anything on that... will be interested to hear how you go with the structure refresh.

Comment: I ended up having sql script write batch script dynamically and execute the batch script at the end of the process. Apparently you only need to copy over all the .cub,.dim,.dsv along with corresponding directories from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\OLAP\Data\[dataset name].db\ to the destination server and this can easily be done with xcopy (or robocopy). You then need to restart the analysis server so it detect the structure changes.